# jQuery - on form submit trigger event on page load

Tags: jquery, forms, triggers, form-submit

I have a login form, when you Click the login button the form fadesIn(), then when the user submits the page it is reloaded with the Error validation.

The issue is, Once the page loads again, the form box doesn't appear because there was no trigger from the login button. Is there a way that once the form has been submitted, the javascript automatically fadesIn the form box again?

example

```
//Login trigger
<a href="#" class="login">Login</a>

//Form that appears on trigger
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
<label>Username</label><input type="text" name="username" />
<label>Password</label><input type="password" name="password" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

JQuery

```
$("a.login").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("form").fadeIn("200");
});
```

User submits form -> page reloads -> want the page to automatically trigger the login handler so the form fades back in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution could be to use Jquery .trigger(): http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Something like `$("a.login")).trigger('click');` when your are in a case you want to simulate a click on `$("a.login"))`

Comment: I was thinking that but the page will reload when the submit is pressed so won't the js re-load and the trigger won't be activated?

Comment: You can add an input hidden on the reloaded page. If this input is set you use the trigger function. Like `if ($('#autofadein').val() == 1){$("a.login")).trigger('click');}`

Answer (score 2):

Can you wrap the form in a div and make it hidden by CSS. Then upon click event use jQuery show() or change CSS to show the div with the form.

Answer (score 0):

Wont this help:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //show the form
  $("form").fadeIn("200");
});
```

Comment: No because that will show the form constantly, I only want it to show the form when it's validated or when the user clicks "login". Not always show it.